# custom keyboard in telegram doesn't work

Tags: php, php-telegram-bot

I wrote this code with PHP for Custom keyboard in Telegram bot but when code executed it return a 400 bad request error );

any idea?

**CODE :**

```
 $botToken = "bot token";
 $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken."/";

 $Bot_reply=urlencode("Welcome");
 $reply_markup = json_encode(
  array(
    "keyboard" => array(
      array("[A]","[B]","[C]"),
      array('[D]','[E]','[F]'),
      array('[G]','[H]','[I]'),
    ),
    "resize_keyboard" => true,
    "one_time_keyboard" => true,
  )
);

$url = $website."sendMessage?chat_id={$user_id}&reply_markup={$reply_markup}&text={$text}";

$callback = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), TRUE);

print_r($callback);
```

Comment: Hey there, please remove your bot token from the code example!! It is your unique token which should not be shared with anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys After googling I found the answer

that was easy we should determine the object as Array

like this

```
 $reply_markup = json_encode(
 array(
"keyboard" => array(
  array(array(text =>"A"),array(text =>"b"),array(text =>"c")),
),
"resize_keyboard" => true,
"one_time_keyboard" => true,
)
);
```